# Change the datagridview colour based on date

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i got a datagridview which displays data from database(MS Access)

the datagridview display the data correctly..

now i want to change the colour of the dgvReminder's row to yellow if current date is less than 2 days to the Date_Of_Pickup.

Date_Of_Pickup is in this format = `19-Dec-2013`

So far i have test this code :-

```
Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
For i As Integer = 0 To dgvReminder.Rows.Count - 1
            If dgvReminder.Rows(i).Cells("Quantity").Value < 2 Then
                dgvReminder.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

The whole Quantity column which has value less than 2 turn to yellow

but how can i do this with the Date_Of_Pickup column??

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,dgvReminder.Rows(i).Cells("Date_Of_Pickup").Value,Now()) > 2) Then
     dgvReminder.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End If
```

Comment: For i As Integer = 0 To dgvReminder.Rows.Count - 1
           If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,dgvReminder.Rows(i).Cells("Date_Of_Pickup").Value,Now()) > 2) [ got an eror " end of statement " here ] Then
                dgvReminder.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            End If
        Next

Answer (score 0):

I did this one and it works , I just checked if the record is expired or about to expire within ongoing month. you can just change the date interval as your need. I used DataBinding Complete event of Data GridView

```
Private Sub grdMembersInfo_DataBindingComplete(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles grdMembersInfo.DataBindingComplete
    For i = 0 To grdMembersInfo.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim expDate As Date = grdMembersInfo.Rows(i).Cells("iCardExpiryDate").Value
        If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Date.Now, expDate) <= 0 Then
            grdMembersInfo.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
        Else
            grdMembersInfo.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```