# Option Strict On prohibits operands type object

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I've got this error on my code `Option Strict On prohibits operands type object operator '<'`
I want to change the row color of DataGridView  to serves as warning if product quantity is < 100

here's my code.

```
Dim drv As DataRowView
    Dim ds As DataSet
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex <= ds.Tables("tbl_Stocks").Rows.Count - 1 Then
            drv = ds.Tables("tbl_Stocks").DefaultView.Item(e.RowIndex)
            Dim c As Color

            If drv.Item("Quantity") < 100 Then
                c = Color.LightBlue
            Else
                c = Color.Pink
            End If
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = c
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

the error was thrown to `If drv.Item("Quantity") < 100`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(drv.Item("Quantity"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get value of needed type through `Row` member which is `DataRow` type

```
Dim value As Integer = drv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity")
```

Extension method `Field(Of T)("columnName")` will cast value to the type you need.
And it will be tiny tiny faster then other casting methods

When using `Option Strict On` you will get faster feedback by compiler about possible mistakes.

Comment: i have a new problem on the ds.tables("tbl_Stocks") it says: Variable ds is used before it has been assign a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. what does it mean?

Comment: by the way i get the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378538/change-the-row-color-in-datagridview-based-on-the-quantity-of-a-cell-value we have the same problem so i try the suggestions here

Comment: i found the answer! I use this code `For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows 
    If rw.Cells("ROWNAME").Value =1 Then 
    rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else 
    rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If 
    Next`

Comment: I affraid your answer will work only with `Option Strict Off`. Because `rw.Cells("ROWNAME").Value` return `Object` type